# Maintaining symmetry?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, metric-tensor

Minkowski metric is found to be
$$ds^2=-dt^2+dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2$$
where $d\Omega^2$ is the metric on a **unit two-sphere**.

Why should we keep track of the $d\Omega^2$ so that spherical symmetry holds well?

Comment: You're not going to have spherical symmetry if you multiply by a general coefficient.

Comment: But you can multiply $dt^2$ and $dr^2$ by a coefficient JUST not $d\Omega^2$. Why? @0celo7

Comment: That's incorrect. If that's the quote from Carroll found [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/213603/what-did-sean-carroll-mean-by-this-sentence), then he means by a function of $r$ alone. The coordinate $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is left invariant by rotations, so functions of $r$ are also rotationally invariant.

Comment: For example, multiplying by something like $xyz/r^3$ breaks rotational symmetry because the product $xyz$ is not rotationally invariant.

Comment: I'm not editing the question on this point, but I usually see $d\Omega$ rather than $d\Omega^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we mean by spherical symmetry is that if we take our geometry and consider the surface at constant $r$ it will have the same geometry as a spherical shell, that is the metric will be:

$$ ds^2 = R^2 \left( d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta \, d\phi^2 \right) \tag{1} $$

where $R$ is some arbitrary constant. If we refer back to [your previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/213603/what-did-sean-carroll-mean-by-this-sentence) we find a proposal for writing the metric as:

$$ ds^2 = -e^{2\alpha(r)}dt^2 + e^{2\beta(r)}dr^2 + e^{2\gamma(r)}r^2 \left( d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta \, d\phi^2 \right) \tag{2} $$

with $\alpha(r)$, $\beta(r)$ and $\gamma(r)$ being arbitrary functions of $r$. Taking a spherical shell means considering constant $r$ and $t$, so $dt = dr = 0$, and equation (2) becomes:

$$\begin{align}
 ds^2 &= e^{2\gamma(r)}r^2 \left( d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta \, d\phi^2 \right) \\
      &= R^2 \left( d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta \, d\phi^2 \right)
\end{align}$$

where the constant $R = e^{2\gamma(r)}r$. Since this is the same as equation (1) we know that it is a spherically symmetric metric.

Given the above it should be obvious that if we mess with the form of $d\Omega^2$ we won't get a spherically symmetric metric. For example we could extend our metric (2) to:

$$ ds^2 = -e^{2\alpha(r)}dt^2 + e^{2\beta(r)}dr^2 + e^{2\gamma(r)}r^2 d\theta^2 + e^{2\delta(r)}r^2 \sin^2\theta \, d\phi^2 \tag{3} $$

But at constant $t$ and $r$ we get:

$$ ds^2 = e^{2\gamma(r)}r^2 d\theta^2 + e^{2\delta(r)}r^2 \sin^2\theta \, d\phi^2 $$

and this cannot be written in the form of equation (1) so it does not have spherical symmetry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In equation (3) you multiplied the 2 terms in $d\Omega^2$ by different coefficients, i.e., the first by $e^{2\gamma (r)}$ and the second by $e^{2\delta (r)}$. Thus, it turns out that this form can NOT be written as in (1). Okay, but what if we multiplied both terms by the same factor, say $e^{\alpha (r)}$, then we can write it as in (1), isn't it? If so, $d\Omega^2$ can be multiplied by other coefficients too which contradicts with the statement in my original question

Comment: @Beyond-formulas: Correct. You can multiply the $d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta \, d\phi^2$ term by an arbitrary function of $r$, just as I did in equation (2), and the metric will stay spherically symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

See your own question here: [Why do people put exponentials there](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/213603/89784)

You can multiply by functions of $r$ on each of the terms.  What you cannot generally do is "muck" with the $r^2 d\Omega$ part itself.  That's what gives you the part of the distance that corresponds to the angular directions on the sphere.  If you change that, then depending on where you are, you'll get different proper distance traveled for different amounts of angle traversed.  I'm being a little sloppy in the language here, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Sorry Brick, but I have not understood the structure of two sentences. "That's what gives you the part of the distance that corresponds to the angular directions on the sphere. If you change that, then depending on where you are, you'll get different proper distance traveled for different amounts of angle traversed." If you may rephrase?

Comment: As you put it, $d\Omega$ is the metric on the unit sphere in these coordinates.  The metric on the sphere with radius $r$ is $r^2 d\Omega$.  If you change this to something else (other than as part of a coordinate transformation), you will lose the symmetry in the "angular" directions on the sphere at each radius. @Beyond-formulas

Comment: But why would I lose angular direction? Say I was at angle 30 degree in 2D plane. Then I extended my ray that was previously pointing at 30 degrees. It will remain at 30 degrees. No angular direction changes as I decrease or increase the length of my ray, isn't it?